Making the repos of a GitHub Pages private but still publicly accessible?
I've been using GitHub for a while but just for personal use so I make all of my repositories private and then just go from there.
However I made a small website using GitHub Pages and from what I understand I need to keep it public in order for others to access it, but that means the repository will also become accessible/editable?
So is there a workaround for this to keep the repos private while still allowing people to view the website?

The public repository is visible, but nobody can edit anything if you don't add them explicitly as collaborators.

"GitHub Pages sites are publicly available on the internet, even if the repository for the site is private."
